# ie8 different display on different computers, but same doctype setting

Tags: internet-explorer-8, doctype

I have a weird problem with doctype, the weird thing is that the website design looks different on the pages.

I have defined doctype, from the same browser, I mean from ie8. The only different things in this condition, is different computers, btw the OS is the same.

I tried to define all of the types of doctypes, no result, still different in designs... what can be the problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different computers, different settings. This is totally user depending. I'm pretty sure the errors are located in something like **Text-Zoom**, default **OS/Browser Text-Size** or an **not installed Font**.

Did you have checked those options?

Comment: Text-Zoom, OS/Browser Text-Size, and not installed Font where i can check them out? btw, we even tried to update ie8 to ie9, didnt help

Comment: Within the Browsersettings. I don't the know the english version of this browser so maybe you'll find it under view or settings. http://www.broomgrove-trust.co.uk/text-zoom-instructions.asp

Comment: Browser Versions are the same? Maybe you have enabled the compatibility Mode? http://www.halilibrahimnuroglu.net/Admin/Medya/image/Makaleler/uyumlulukmodu.jpg